# Default amount of memory allocated for Windows Docker containers?

Tags: docker-for-windows, docker

What is the default amount of memory that's assigned to Docker for Windows containers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Docker for Windows containers get:

- when using Hyper-V isolation (ie. on Windows 10), 1GB of memory
- when using process isolation, unlimited (same as host) memory

The details are documented here:
https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/32724/files#diff-505c72218d90da970c16fdbf0b4f613c

When using docker-compose this means that you need to explicitly set the memory limit, e.g.

```
services:
 mssql:
  image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express
  mem_limit: 4096m
```

to have 4GB of memory available.

Comment: Is there a way to set this limits globally per CLI, i.e. to avoid specifying this on every run, much like with the Docker for Windows UI but on the command line?